# Turn this idea into a Java formula

Tags: java, plot, bukkit

I am making a plot assignment program (for a Bukkit plugin).

There is a world with sandstone slabs placed along every multiple of 200 (`x` and `z` axis). I then assign a plot to a player, and get the location of the plot ID with this code:

```
double zCorner = (Math.floor(plotID / 200)) * 200;
double xCorner = (plotID % 200) * 200;
```

I would like to do this backwards, i.e. recover the plot ID from the `zCorner` and `xCorner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `xCorner / 200` holds the remainder of `plotId` divided by 200.
- `yCorner / 200` holds the quotient of `plotId` divided by 200.

You could then write the following:

```
double recoveredPlotID = (zCorner / 200) * 200 + xCorner / 200;
```

to get the `plotID` from the two corners.

Comment: @user1945309525 You can do it, yes.